# Passing metafile to fastreport masterdata image control

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I need to pass a graphic (Metafile) to an `image1` control on masterdata band for each printed record.

Unfortunately, I can't use the `LoadFromFile` method in `OnBeforePrint` event, since the metafile is part of another file and I have to extract it before and then pass it to masterdata's control.

I tried with the user function declaring option, but they use the `Variant` type, therefore, I can't assign a metafile.

Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an user function accepting the name of the picture object and any other parameter you need from the report.

```
frxReport1.AddFunction(
  'procedure MyTest(const APicViewName : string)',
  'CustomFunctions',
  'This is the description of the MyTest function'
);
```

Define the function:

```
procedure TForm1.MyTest(const APicViewName : string);
var
  Pic : TfrxPictureView;
  Stream : TStream;
begin
  Pic := TfrxPictureView(frxReport1.FindObject(APicViewName));
  if(not Assigned(Pic)) or (not Pic.ClassType.InheritsFrom(TfrxPictureView)) then
    Exit;



  Stream := <TMemoryStream/TFileStream/...>.Create;
  try
    //load and process your image as you need and load it into the Stream
    //...

    Stream.Position := 0;
    Pic.LoadPictureFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;

end;
```

In `frxReport1.OnUserFunction` event handler:

```
function TForm1.frxReport1UserFunction(const MethodName: string; var Params: Variant): Variant;
begin
  if(MethodName = 'MYTEST')
  then MyTest(Params[0]);
end;
```

Comment: first of all thank you. The solution works in half. That is, it always prints the same image. The procedure has the same name as the file.
I don't understand what tmpcurreport means, would it be the TfrxReport class report object? We're almost there. What can I do?

Comment: @BartolomeoGiorgio: My error, TmpCurReport is the TfrxReport object, I've updated the answer

Comment: Ok, but why the procedure is called only once? (I set up a breakpoint) In the preview, there is the same picture. Thanks again.

Comment: @BartolomeoGiorgio: How do you determinate which image to load? (Do you have an Id, a filename... in the dataset?)

Comment: @BartolomeoGiorgio: If so, make sure the image is placed inside the report's band, and that the report's band is linked to the dataset who contains the key information for the image loading (Id, filename... or anything you're using for determinating which is the right image to load)

Comment: The report runs well. All fields change their values and the filename field too. Only the picture field not change. In fact, the app stops only one time at the breakpoint into my procedure.

Comment: @BartolomeoGiorgio: How do you determinate which image to load? (Do you have an Id, a filename... in the dataset?)

Comment: Each record has a field that contains the filename to be processed.

Comment: I pass the value of this field to my procedure

Comment: @BartolomeoGiorgio: Ok, try to: 1) make sure that the image is inside the band. 2) make sure the band is linked to the same dataset of your filename. 3) make sure the report image control has its DataSet property evalued with the same dataset of the band. 4) call your user function from the report image's OnBeforePrint event handler

Comment: Thanks, I solved. There was a problem with onbeforeprint event; It was written badly. Thanks again

Comment: @BartolomeoGiorgio: Great! [Accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you